# How to combine data from two kafka topics ZStreams to one ZStream?

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, zio

```
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
import zio.blocking.Blocking
import zio.clock.Clock
import zio.console.{Console, putStrLn}
import zio.kafka.consumer.{CommittableRecord, Consumer, ConsumerSettings, Subscription}
import zio.kafka.consumer.Consumer.{AutoOffsetStrategy, OffsetRetrieval}
import zio.kafka.serde.Serde
import zio.stream.ZStream
import zio.{ExitCode, Has, URIO, ZIO, ZLayer}

object Test2Topics extends zio.App {
  val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass)

  val consumerSettings: ConsumerSettings =
    ConsumerSettings(List("localhost:9092"))
      .withGroupId(s"consumer-${java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString}")
      .withOffsetRetrieval(OffsetRetrieval.Auto(AutoOffsetStrategy.Earliest))

  val consumer: ZLayer[Clock with Blocking, Throwable, Has[Consumer]] =
    ZLayer.fromManaged(Consumer.make(consumerSettings))

  val streamString: ZStream[Any with Has[Consumer], Throwable, CommittableRecord[String, String]] =
    Consumer.subscribeAnd(Subscription.topics("test"))
      .plainStream(Serde.string, Serde.string)

  val streamInt: ZStream[Any with Has[Consumer], Throwable, CommittableRecord[String, String]] =
    Consumer.subscribeAnd(Subscription.topics("topic"))
      .plainStream(Serde.string, Serde.string)
  val combined = streamString.zipWithLatest(streamInt)((a,b)=>(a,b))
  val program = for {
    fiber1 <- streamInt.tap(r => putStrLn(s"streamInt: ${r.toString}")).runDrain.forkDaemon
    fiber2 <- streamString.tap(r => putStrLn(s"streamString: ${r.toString}")).runDrain.forkDaemon
  } yield ZIO.raceAll(fiber1.join, List(fiber2.join))
  override def run(args: List[String]): URIO[zio.ZEnv, ExitCode] = {
    //combined.tap(r => putStrLn(s"Combined: ${r.toString}")).runDrain.provideSomeLayer(consumer ++ Console.live).exitCode
    program.provideSomeLayer(consumer ++ Console.live).exitCode
  }
}
```

Somehow when i try to combine the output from two topics with names test and topic i dont get any output printed out, and also when i try to print both streams in parallel that also doesnt work, but if i print just one stream at a time it works.

Did anyone experience anything like this?

Comment: If you want to join topics, why not use Kafka Streams Scala API?

Comment: Well that is the simplest thing i need to do but somehow it doesnt work, well zio streams provide much more operations to work with the streams compared to Kafka Streams Scala Api - that is why i need to use them, but i am surprised that somehow i cannot do even stuff as simple as that

Comment: There is more in Kafka Streams than simply consuming both topics at once. There is time windowing required to join the data as well. In any case, `Subscription.topics()` should be able to take multiple topics at once, or a regex pattern, like the plain Kafka consumer API, so do you really need two separate subscriptions?

Comment: well this was the simplest example i could come up with in our real application we have multiple topics with different types of data in them, not neccessarily strings

Comment: That doesn't prevent you from [using multiple topics in the same subscription](https://github.com/zio/zio-kafka/blob/master/docs/gettingStarted.md#partition-assignment-and-offset-retrieval). It just means you'd need to use `Array[Byte]` (`Serde.bytes`?) and call different deserializer methods manually within if statements based on the record's topic names, assuming you didn't have generic JSON / Avro parsers, for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are composing 1 shared layer that provides one instance of a consumer and initialize this instance twice after eachother to subscribe to 2 topics one after the other.
A single consumer instance should only be initialized once, so the above code will never work.

I believe setting up 2 independent compositions of consumer to stream like this will help:

```scala
val program = for {
    fiber1 <- streamInt.tap(r => putStrLn(s"streamInt: ${r.toString}")).runDrain.forkDaemon.provideSomeLayer(consumer)
    fiber2 <- streamString.tap(r => putStrLn(s"streamString: ${r.toString}")).runDrain.forkDaemon.provideSomeLayer(consumer)
  } yield {...}
```